# Is it possible to get the frequency a specific node publishes to a topic?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know `rostopic hz /topic` gives the total frequency, but can I get the frequency a particular node publishes to a topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363285/is-it-possible-to-get-the-frequency-a-specific-node-publishes-to-a-topic?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-10-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-13**:
Look into the topic statistics functionality. But note it does have its disadvantages / inaccuracies.

**Comment by [runtao](https://answers.ros.org/users/60564/runtao/) on 2020-10-15**:
what disadvantages the topic statistics have exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not ideal, but you could replace that single publisher with a [DiagnosedPublisher](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/diagnostic_updater/html/classdiagnostic__updater_1_1DiagnosedPublisher.html) which publishes some statistics on a separate topic.

---

Originally posted by [Rayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/46652/rayman/) with karma: 128 on 2020-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1